# Documentum REST API

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, emc, documentum-dfs

I'm trying to develop a ESB connector for Documentum REST API. According to the information they have provided in their website, both the Documentum Content Server and the Documentum Core REST are required to user the API.

I want to know whether the content server and the Documentum Core REST are free to download and use.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, How to get Documentum login username and password from OpenText?
Please let me know anything required.

Answer (score 4):

No, nothing of EMC Documentum software is free to download or use. You need to signup for some kind of partner programs with EMC (not my area, though).

However, since year or so EMC opened their community and forums publicly so you can find helpful details just googling.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting to clarify that Documentum is no longer owned by EMC, it is Opentext now (since 2016). As it was previously said, there's no free version available, you need to have a customer/partner account in order to access the downloads on support.opentext.com